# What kind of elliptical construction would the following interpretation fall into and what are some similar examples?

Tags: phrase-usage, sentence-patterns, ellipses, construction

Here is the sentence construction:

> As you come to him, a living stone rejected by men but in the sight of
> God chosen and precious, you yourselves like living stones are being
> built up.

I want to argue that the phrase "rejected by men but in the sight of God chosen and precious" is implied in the second part of the sentence. In other words I want to argue for an elliptical construction like this:

> As you come to him, a living stone rejected by men but in the sight of
> God chosen and precious, you yourselves like living stones (rejected
> by men but in the sight of God chosen and precious) are being built
> up.

What kind of elliptical construction would this be and what are some other examples of it? If it is not an elliptical construction, what kind of construction is it?

Comment: Comparing your versions, you could imagine ellipsis in the first if it leaves out the repetition of the second. Do you think, though, that in a medium length sentence a reader will forget what the writer uses living stones to represent? And need to be reminded?

Comment: The parenthetical appositive (a living stone rejected by men but in the sight of God chosen and precious) applies strictly only to _him_, and applying part of it to the second mention of 'living stones' is linguistically very dubious. 'He was a good man (a man of the country, who loved to hike in the Dales), and you men of the country are good men too.' // Though John 15:20b, I Peter 2:9a, and I Peter 3:4c show that the result is not heretical.

Comment: "A living stone rejected by men but in the sight of God chosen and precious" is ascriptive, not specifying, and hence not an appositive.,